# Presentation of a hierachical Type in a Tree or CellTree by GWT

Tags: java, gwt, tree, selection

I want to display a hierachical Type in a cellTree. When i select one Item, I want to display it's details on the screen. 
Type A contains a list of B, B a list of C etc.
I have 5 levels, therefore i would have to write 5 `SelectionModel<T>` for every Type.
Is there another way, than implement for every Type a own `SingleSelectionModel<T>`, or write only one `SingleSelectionModel<Object>` and use instanceof?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using an interface for my hierachical Type. It provides a Method which gives back an Enum, that identifies the correct implementation of the Interface. So i was able to write just one `SelectionModel<Interface>`.